# Very large excel file - how to copy data between sheets?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to to import some csv files into excel 2010 and create a very simple, but very large database.
The whole story will be - five columns and thousands of rows.
VBA is also simple - copy data from one sheet to another - and vice versa.
But I need to care about memory requirement, because of potentially very large file size.

```
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim r1 As Range
Dim r2 As Range
Set ws1 = Sheets("01")
Set ws2 = Sheets("02")
Set r1 = ws1.Range("A1:B10") ' for example
Set r2 = ws2.Range("C5:D14")
r1.Copy Destination:=r2 'first way
r2.Value = r1.Value ' second way
```

Is there any differences between this two methods, in the scope of memory/time consuming?
At the and I will have over 10,000 rows. What will be the size of the file?

Comment: `Is there any differences between this two methods, in the scope of memory/time consuming?` Try! Try! Try! Put a timer in your code and test your methods against each other. `What will be the size of the file?` Same answer as above. Impossible to tell without seeing a dataset.

Comment: `Instant` - depends on what your definition of that word is. For your row size in Excel, I doubt it you will find anything meeting your defintion. I've posted some code below for CSV imports that will likely be more efficiently than opening a csv and copying the data from workbook to workbook. If it doesn't help, let me know. I will delete as an "answer".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code block had some specifics for a project I was on, but should help get you started on how to import CSV files (somewhat cleaning) through VBA:

```
Public Sub ImportCSV(strPath As String, strFile As String, strExt As String, wbDestination As Workbook, Optional wsDest As Worksheet, Optional strRange As String, Optional blHeaders As Boolean = True)
'imports given CSV file into given sheet at given range _
    defaults to comma separated delimiters

Dim wsDestination As Worksheet
Dim strFileName As String
strFileName = strPath & strFile & ".csv"


If wsDest Is Nothing Then Set wsDestination = wbDestination.Worksheets.Add(, wbDestination.Worksheets(wbDestination.Worksheets.Count)) Else: Set wsDestination = wsDest
If strRange = "" Then strRange = "$A$1"

With wsDestination.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & strFileName, Destination:=wsDestination.Range(strRange))
        .FieldNames = False
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = False
        .AdjustColumnWidth = False
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        .Delete
    End With

If Not blHeaders Then wsDestination.Range(strRange).EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: Scott, this is much more than an answer. Moreover, I received some additional ideas reading your code. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6):

You can utilize ADO to query text files as if they were a database table. This allows you to write SQL queries to pull data out of your text files. You can do this any text file or even .xls files if you wanted to.

The code/process for doing so is fairly simple. You'll need to reference the Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.X Library first and then use something like the following:

```
Dim cn as New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs as New ADODB.Recordset
Dim i as Integer

With cn
    .Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source=C:\SomeFolder;" & _
                        "Extended Properties=""text; HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited"""
    .Open

    With rs
        .Open "SELECT * from fileName.txt", cn

        'Loop through each row in query
        While Not (.EOF Or .BOF)
            'Loop through each column in row
            For i = 0 to .Fields.Count - 1
                Debug.Print .Fields(i).Value 'Print value of field to Immediate Window
            Next i

            .MoveNext
        Wend

        .Close
    End With

    .Close
End With

Set rs = Nothing
Set cn = Nothing
```

This will loop through your text file and display the value of the first column in your VBA immediate window. It also assumes that your file has header rows. If it does not then you need to alter **HDR** in your ConnectionString to *No*.

The code will automatically try and infer types for you but if you're running into issues with it not discovering the correct type (such as leading zeros) then you can explicity define a schema for your file. It's important to note that if you go the schema route then your ConnectionString arguments like **HDR** and **FMT** *WILL BE IGNORED*. They will retain their default settings as defined in the Registry unless you override them in the schema definition. More info on schema.ini files can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms709353(v=vs.85).aspx.

Here is another useful link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974559.aspx. It's an article written by the Microsoft Scripting Guys and is how I originally learned about the process.

Lastly, if you ever use this process with .xls files then you should know that you should NEVER query an OPEN .xls file. There's a nasty memory leak bug with OPEN .xls files (more info here: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;319998&Product=xlw). As long as you query CLOSED .xls documents then you shouldn't have any issues whatsoever =D. The syntax in the SQL FROM clause is a bit different since you have to target particular sheet but IIRC the Scripting Guys article I linked explains how to do so.

Comment: Kittoes, Thanks very much for your efforts, and especially for your explanations. I need to study this approach.

Comment: @Alegro NP. When importing any data from text files into Excel (or Access) I prefer this approach because it's quick and extremely flexible. I also love it because it follows nearly the same logic/syntax as pulling data from actual databases. If I was querying data from say SQL Server then the only things I'd have to change would be the SELECT statement and the Provider/Driver/Connection string. The ability to constrain what gets imported with nothing more than a simple WHERE clause is also very awesome.

Comment: Kittoes, I love universal solutions. I see now, your code is really precious. Thanks a Lot. Once more: Thanks Man.

Comment: @Alegro lol, just paying it forward. When I came across that MSDN arcticle I literally said out loud "No way." It's just crazy how easily you can use it with everything. Keep in mind that looping through the records like I did above isn't the ONLY way you can handle the data returned by your query. You can really use your imagination and figure out what's best for particular project. In theory you could even end up putting the data into an Excel table similar to what Scott did above.