# Vbscript to import csv into excel

Tags: excel, csv, vbscript, import

I would like to make a VBSript that will open a csv of varying rows and columns and paste them starting at row 4 column 1. So far what I have written is slow and has the amount of columns hard coded into it.

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(wscript.Arguments(0))
objExcel.Visible = True
objExcel.Cells(1, 4).Value = wscript.Arguments(1)+" - "+wscript.Arguments(2)
objExcel.Cells(2, 4).Value = wscript.Arguments(3)

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile (wscript.Arguments(4))
cCount = 1
rCount = 4

Do While objTextFile.AtEndOfStream <> True
        arrUserRecord = split(objTextFile.Readline, ",")
        Do While cCount<213
            objExcel.Cells(rCount, cCount).Value = arrUserRecord(cCount-1)
            cCount=cCount+1
        Loop
        cCount=1
        rCount=1+rCount
Loop
```

Comment: The answer in this question is VBA, but perhaps you can edit it into your VBScript through the Excel file to import the CSV... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12466793/very-large-excel-file-how-to-copy-data-between-sheets/12467235#12467235

Answer (score 4):

Excel can be rather particular about what it accepts as "valid CSV". I had to resort to the following on several occasions:

```
Const vbFormatStandard = 1
Const vbFormatText     = 2
Const vbFormatDate     = 4

Const xlDelimited      = 1
Const xlDoubleQuote    = 1

' change according to number/type of the fields in your CSV
dataTypes = Array( Array(1, vbFormatText) _
  , Array(2, vbFormatStandard) _
  , Array(3, vbFormatText) _
  , Array(4, vbFormatDate) _
  )

Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xl.Visible = True

xl.Workbooks.OpenText "input.csv", , , xlDelimited, xlDoubleQuote, False _
  , False, True, , , , dataTypes
Set wb = xl.ActiveWorkbook
```

Comment: +1 good technique (alternative to schema.ini) and implementation.

Answer (score 1):

If its a valid CSV file, then Excel can open it directly.  So just write your VBscript to tell Excel to open the CSV file as though it was a workbook.  Then you can copy the data you want from that workbook into your workbook.

---

If you don't know how to do this, then VBA is the best way, but you should be able to mock it up in VBscript as well.  Here is what I think it should look like, though I cannot test to be sure:

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(wscript.Arguments(0))
objExcel.Visible = True
objExcel.Cells(1, 4).Value = wscript.Arguments(1) + " - " + wscript.Arguments(2)
objExcel.Cells(2, 4).Value = wscript.Arguments(3)

Set objWorksheet = objWorkbook.ActiveSheet

Set objWbkCsv = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(wscript.Arguments(4))
Set objWksCsv = objWbkCsv.Worksheets(1)
Set objRangeSource = objWksCsv.UsedRange

cCount = objRangeSource.Columns.Count
rCount = objRangeSource.Rows.Count + (4 - 1)
Set objRangeDest = objWorksheet.Range(objWorksheet.Cells(4, 1), objWorksheet.Cells(rCount, cCount))

objRangeSource.Copy objRangeDest
```

Comment: What is the best way to copy entire excel file and paste it into other excel file starting at row 4?

Comment: The objRangeSource should be Set by using objWksCsv.UsedRange (and not *all* Cells).

Comment: Excel wouldn't necessarily open a "valid CSV" file 'cuz [it uses the list delimiter from locale settings instead of a comma](https://superuser.com/questions/606272/how-to-get-excel-to-interpret-the-comma-as-a-default-delimiter-in-csv-files). `OpenText` is the correct way.