# Convert .csv file into Excel in VBScript

Tags: excel, vbscript, csv

I'm writing a program to convert a .csv file into an Excel file in VBScript.

This is the portion of my .csv file (It has a header as well)

> Report Title,Goods Performance Characteristics Report,,Report
>   Title,Goods Performance Characteristics Report,,,,,,, Begin
>   Date,8/7/2012,,,,,,,,,, Template
>   Name,XXXX-Test-VVV-Two-Positions,,,,,,,,,, Total
>   Productions,,,,,,,,,,,
>
> ,ID,Name,Product Description,Issue Date,Product Type,Weight
>   (kg),Weight (lb),Price,Product volume, Profit,Total Value (000)
>   ,315616102,Lux Honey,Body
>   Wash,8/1/2012,C,0.06,0.06,93,793920,0,7455703038 ,579780206,Clear
>   AntiDandruf,Shampoo,8/1/2012,C,0.06,0.06,60.5,1325980,2.05,8022179000
>   ,761713106,Loreal Divine,Face
>   Crub,8/1/2012,F,0.12,0.12,46.52,3314780,5.07,15420356560

This is the **updated** VBScript code I wrote for the conversion.

```
Dim xlApp, workBook1, workBook2,aSheets, fileName, aInfo2,aInfo1,oExcel
  Const XlPlatform = "xlWindows"
  Const xlDelimited = 1
  Const xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote = 1
  Const xlTextFormat = 2
  Const xlGeneralFormat = 1


  Set oExcel = Sys.OleObject("Excel.Application")  
  Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")  

  Set workBook1 = xlApp.ActiveWorkBook

  Set workBook1 = xlApp.WorkBooks.OpenText("Y:\Personal Folders\XXXX\TestFile1.csv",XlPlatform, 1, xlDelimited, xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote, true, false, false, true, false, true, "CRLF", Array(Array (1,2),Array (2,2),Array (3,2),Array (4,1),Array (5,2),Array (6,1),Array (7,1),Array (8,1),Array (9,1),Array (10,1),Array (11,1)), true, false)

  Set workBook1 = xlApp.ActiveWorkBook
  xlApp.Visible = true

  workBook1.Save "Y:\Personal Folders\XXXX\x.xlsx", xlNormal
  workBook1.Close
```

But the data is not in a tabular form in the Excel file.I want  to display the data in a tabular form.
Could anyone please help me to extract data based on the delimeters.I need the header part in the excel file as well.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several issues with the code from your updated question:

- `Const XlPlatform = "xlWindows"`

  `XlPlatform` must be a numeric value, not a string. The `xlWindows` member of the [enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlplatform%28v=office.11%29.aspx) has the value `2`. However, since that's the default anyway, you can simply omit this value when calling `OpenText`.
- `Set workBook1 = xlApp.ActiveWorkBook`

  A newly spawned Excel instance doesn't have an active workbook, so it's pointless to assign that to a variable before you actually open or create a workbook.
- `Set workBook1 = xlApp.WorkBooks.OpenText(...)`

  The `OpenText` method does not return an object, so there's nothing to assign in the above statement.
- `...ooks.OpenText(..., true, "CRLF", ...)`

  The string `"CRLF"` is not a character. Why do you want to specify line-breaks as separator-characters anyway?
- `..., Array(...), true, false)`

  The last 2 parameters you specified are `TextVisualLayout` (specifies left-to-rigt/right-to-left) and `DecimalSeparator`. Both of them are not boolean values. Simply omit them if you don't know for certain that you need them.
- `workBook1.Save "Y:\Personal Folders\XXXX\x.xlsx", xlNormal`

  The `Save` method saves a workbook under its current name. To save a workbook under a different name you must use the [`SaveAs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.saveas%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) method. The constant `xlNormal` isn't defined anywhere in your code. Plus, `xlNormal` produces an Excel 97/2003 workbook (`.xls`). To save a workbook as an Excel 2007/2010 workbook (`.xlsx`) you must use the `xlOpenXMLWorkbook` constant.

The following code worked for me:

```
Const xlDelimited                =  1
Const xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote =  1
Const xlOpenXMLWorkbook          = 51

Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

xl.Workbooks.OpenText "Y:\Personal Folders\XXXX\TestFile1.csv", , , xlDelimited _
  , xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote, True, False, False, True, False, False, _
  , Array(Array(1,2), Array(2,2), Array(3,2), Array(4,1), Array(5,2) _
  , Array(6,1), Array(7,1), Array(8,1), Array(9,1), Array(10,1), Array(11,1))
Set wb = xl.ActiveWorkbook

wb.SaveAs "Y:\Personal Folders\XXXX\x.xlsx", xlOpenXMLWorkbook, , , , False
wb.Close

xl.Quit
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Excel 2003.The following is a code I got to specify the .csv file format

```
Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Set wb = xl.Workbooks.OpenText "input.csv", , , xlDelimited, xlDoubleQuote, _
  False, False, True, , , , dataTypes
```

from [Vbscript to import csv into excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12961835/vbscript-to-import-csv-into-excel?rq=1)

Could you please **explain the function** of the following line?

```
Set wb = xl.Workbooks.OpenText "input.csv", , , xlDelimited, xlDoubleQuote, _
      False, False, True, , , , dataTypes
```

**My implementation of the OpenText property for the above mentioned .csv file**

```
Set workBook1 = xlApp.WorkBooks.OpenText("D:\Personal Folders\XXXX\TestFile1.csv", , ,xlDelimited, ,false ,false ,false ,True,false ,false ,"~")
```

Comment: [`OpenText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837097.aspx) is the method for importing text files. Since VBScript doesn't support named parameters, you have to specify all parameters in the proper order. You can omit the values for parameters that you want to remain at default value, though, and you can omit trailing default values entirely. The `dataTypes` value is an array that defines the format for each imported column. When the file is opened successfully, the created workbook object is assigned to the variable `wb`.

Comment: Ansgar:Thanks alot for the reply.I learnt there are 12 parameters for the OpenText property.But now I'm getting an error saying "Unable to get the OpenText property of the WorkBooks class".Do you know the reason for this?I edited the obove script with my OpenText version

Comment: I have included my implementation for the OpenText in the above post.Thanks

Comment: `OpenText` doesn't return a workbook object, so you'll have to do assign the workbook object to a variable in a second step: `xlApp.Workbooks.OpenText "...", ..., "~" : Set workBook1 = xlApp.ActiveWorkbook`.

Comment: I'm still getting the error "Unable to get the OpenText property of the WorkBooks class".

Comment: The constant `xlDelimited` is undefined in your script. Add a line `Const xlDelimited = 1`.

Comment: BTW Ansgar I'm running this code in a specific QA editor called TestComplete.Will the editoe will be causing this issue...???http://smartbear.com/products/qa-tools/automated-testing-tools

Answer (score -1):

You need to specify what Format you are saving as. The following will specify it as a standard .xls for 2003

```
    Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
    "D:\Personal Folders\XXXXX\TestFile1.csv"

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "D:\Personal Folders\XXXXX\x.xls", FileFormat:=xlNormal

    ActiveWorkbook.Close
```

Also can try

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "D:\Personal Folders\XXXXX\x.xls", FileFormat:= 56
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Currently I'm using Excel 2003 (.xls).how can I specify the data format in Excel 2003..???

Comment: Try the updated code. It's been a while but I think that is how its done.

Comment: Your code is VBA, not VBScript. Named parameters don't work in VBScript.

Comment: Thanks for the replay.But I'm looking for a VBScript implementation.