# Visual Basic runtime error 1004

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I am trying to write a Visual Basic Script to run by windows task scheduler. The script is supposed to open a delimited text file into excel and then save it as an .xlsx file.

```
Function ImportText()

Path = "C:\Users\username\Documents\"
inFile = "2014_1_31_data_parse.txt"
outFile = "2014_1_31_data_parse.xlsx"

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Workbooks.OpenText FileName:=Path & inFile, Other:=True, OtherChar:="^"

objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=Path & outFile

objExcel.Quit
WScript.Quit
WScript.Echo "Completed"

End Function
```

Currently it gives a Run-time error of 1004 file can not be found. However the file is there.

Comment: Are you sure you are doing this via VBScript? i.e a text file saved as a .vbs file?

Comment: If your path is really "C:\Users\username\Documents\" it's not going to find a file. Unles you actually have a user named "username".

Comment: There are couple of issues with your code besides the path problem i.e if you are `actually` using a .VBS file. See [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15787403/convert-csv-file-into-excel-in-vbscript) link. It will help you create your code.

Comment: I personally can't get this to compile, with it failing on the line `objExcel.Workbooks.OpenTest...`. I don't know that VBScript will actually allow you to pass a string the way you are attempting to do it. In Siddharth's link in fact, they pass the string in quotes, which you may have to do as well.

Comment: @DeanBDean: no quotes is not a problem. He is using a variable. You can't use `FileName:=`, `Other:=` etc and hence I asked OP if he/she is using VBS or VBA. Also the SaveAs, needs the file format to be mentioned. File Format for xlsx is 51 (Excel constant  xlOpenXMLWorkbook)

Comment: @SiddharthRout, thanks for the clarification. I did not realize you couldn't use `FileName:=` etc in VBS.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your code, but the first thing to change is the method call syntax. You are using named parameters (which I guess comes from a recorded macro?).

```
objExcel.Workbooks.OpenText FileName:=Path & inFile, Other:=True, OtherChar:="^"
```

should be changed to

```
objExcel.Workbooks.OpenText Path & InFile, , , , , , , , , , True, "^"
```

That's quite easy to see if you use IntelliSense in the VBA editor.
Once you've solved that, you will have issues with error handling and other stuff that gets harder when the application is invisible, but that's a different story

Comment: This might be a technically correct substitution but I don't agree with the imperative "should". When a method has lots of parameters -- and especially when the parameters are optional -- a list of comma-separated nulls is pretty much meaningless to anyone reviewing the code.

Comment: That's true, but since vbs can't handle named parameters, there isn't much else to do. My "should" is merely a tip on how to cope...

Comment: path = "C:\Users\me\"
inFile = "2014_1_31_data_parse.txt"
outFile = "2014_1_31_data_parse.xlsx"

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Workbooks.OpenText path & inFile,,,,,,,,,, True, "^"

objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs path & outFile, 51 

objExcel.Quit
WScript.Quit
WScript.Echo "Completed"

Comment: this is what I changed it to but it still gives me issues at the beginning of the openText statement.

Comment: If you add objExcel.visible=true just after the createobject line, you will see what your issue is. Now I suspect you have more than a few excel.exe running.