# Import a csv file into Excel and password protect it automatically outside of Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'd like to take a csv (it will either have 2 or 11 entries):

"Hello","There","People",..."11th thing"

or

"Hello","There"

Thanks to
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2005/02/07/how-can-i-password-protect-an-excel-spreadsheet/ I created a password protected Excel file!

Now how to import a csv?

I tried but failed to merge this post into my script:

[Vbscript to import csv into excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12961835/vbscript-to-import-csv-into-excel)

Here's what I've got:

```
vbFormatStandard = 1
Const vbFormatText     = 2
Const vbFormatDate     = 4

Const xlDelimited      = 1
Const xlDoubleQuote    = 1

' change according to number/type of the fields in your CSV
dataTypes = Array( Array(1, vbFormatText) _
  , Array(2, vbFormatStandard) _
  , Array(3, vbFormatText) _
  , Array(4, vbFormatDate) _
  )

Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = FALSE

xl.Visible = True
xl.Workbooks.OpenText "C:\Users\data.csv", , , xlDelimited, xlDoubleQuote, False _  , False, True, , , , dataTypes
Set wb = xl.ActiveWorkbook

Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add
Set objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
objWorksheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = Now
objWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Users\stuff.xls",,"pass"
objExcel.Quit
```

How do I call my objects? I'm not making head or tails and am not a developer, but have this  task....

Comment: Why add the new workbook?  You can just save the existing `wb`

Comment: Because I don't understand exactly how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works instead and is simpler:

```
Dim myXL
Const xlDelimited = 1
Const xlWorkbookNormal = -4143

Set myXL=CreateObject("Excel.Application")
myXL.Visible=False
myXL.DisplayAlerts=False
myXL.WorkBooks.OpenText "C:\data.xt", , , xlDelimited, , , , , True 
myXL.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\data.xls", xlWorkbookNormal,"password"

myXL.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
myXL.Quit

Set myXL = Nothing
```

see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185.aspx for details