# Import Many Text Files into Single Excel Sheet: One Per Row, Filename in Col. A, Contents in B

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to import multiple text files into a single Excel 2016 worksheet. The name of the first text file should go into cell A1, the name of the second text file should go into A2, and so forth. The contents of the first text file should go into cell B1, the contents of the second text file should go into B2, and so forth. What scripting tool or procedure should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a vb Script to do this.

I recommend to record bits of what you need to do and learn from the generated code to write what you need.

You will need a VB function that lists files from a directory. Find some useful tips from  https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2004/10/20/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-the-files-in-a-folder-and-its-subfolders/ for this.

You will need a way to import the text files in excel. For this have a look at [Vbscript to import csv into excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12961835/vbscript-to-import-csv-into-excel)