# split text to rows excel

Tags: file, vba, excel

I have a VBA code with which I import a txt file into one cell.
Here's the code (it's not that important):

```
Sub ReadFile()
     ' Requires a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime (Tools > References)
    Dim FSO As FileSystemObject
    Dim FSOFile As File
    Dim FSOStream As TextStream

    Dim Rand
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

   Set FSO = New FileSystemObject
   Set FSOFile = FSO.GetFile("C:\Users\sdagfsgedg\Desktop\20121122.log")
   Set FSOStream = FSOFile.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading, TristateUseDefault)
   Rand = 1
   Do While Not FSOStream.AtEndOfStream
        ws.Cells(Rand, 1).Value = FSOStream.ReadAll
   Loop
End Sub
```

The text file 20121122.log has about 20.000 lines which are all imported in one cell. How can I split that cell into 20.000 cells (if the log has 20.000 lines). I don't want to read the text file line by line... I want to read it all (it's way more faster) then split every line on a separate row.

LATER EDIT:
Or if there is another solution to read the log file and paste the text as line to row (not everything in one cell as I do right now)

Comment: have you tried using a delimeter? in the text file you can use find and replace and replace " " (a space) with "," or any other delimeter to separate cells with in excel.

Comment: I'm not generating the log and I can't modify it (it's generated by a closed source application).

Comment: Thats ok, you can still accomplish delimiting

Comment: copy the cell's info into word and do it there

Comment: you can change your approach, using the ExcelQuery tools in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12466793/very-large-excel-file-how-to-copy-data-between-sheets/12467235#12467235), you can import your text into your spreadsheet with delimiters and it will import just like an Excel table. The post is set up for `.csv', but it applies to `.txt' files as well. It's also probably faster than looping through each line in the text file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

// Code is not tested

```
Sub ReadFile()
  Dim FSO As FileSystemObject
  Dim FSOFile As File
  Dim FSOStream As TextStream

  Dim Rand
  Dim row
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

  Set FSO = New FileSystemObject
  Set FSOFile = FSO.GetFile("C:\Users\sdagfsgedg\Desktop\20121122.log")
  Set FSOStream = FSOFile.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading, TristateUseDefault)
  Rand = 1
  Dim content As String
  Dim lines As Variant
  Dim intIndex As Integer

  content = FSOStream.ReadAll
  lines = split(content, Chr(10))

  For intIndex = LBound(lines) To UBound(lines)
    ws.Cells(Rand, 1).Value = lines(intIndex)
    Rand = Rand + 1
  Next

End Sub
```